# Multiple tidying operations in one pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

This is more of a code-cleaning exercise I'm doing right now.  What my initial data looks like is this:

```
Year    County    Town  ...  Funding Received ... (90+ Variables total)
2016      a        x               Yes
2015      a        y               No
2014      a        x               Yes
2016      b        z               Yes
```

I couldn't see how I could get a count of submitted and approved applications from this so I transformed it to indicator variables to be counted with the following code:

```
counties <- original_data %>%
  select(county, funded, year) %>%
  mutate(
    a=ifelse(county == "a", 1,0),
    b=ifelse(county == "b", 1,0),
    c=ifelse(county == "c", 1,0),
    ... etc ...
  )
```

And the output looks like

```
County    Funding Received    Year    binary.a    binary.b
  a             Yes           2016       1           0
  a             No            2015       1           0
  b             No            2016       0           1
```

This data was then transformed into two dataframes (submitted and funded) to get a count of each county's submitted and funded applications per year using the following code:

```
countysum <- counties %>%
  select(-funded) %>%
  group_by(county, year) %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm = T)
```

And the output looks like:

```
County    Year    sum.a    sum.b
  a       2016      32       0
  a       2015      24       0
  b       2016       0      16
```

But then to get the data in a tidier format I used a few more commands:

```
countysum$submitted <- rowSums(countysum[,3:15, na.rm = T) #3:15 are county indicator vars
countysum <- countysum[,-c(3:19)]
```

Now my question is: Is there a way to reduce all these actions into a singular pipeline?  Right now I have code that works, but would prefer to have code that works and is a little easier to follow.  Apologies for lack of data, I cannot share it.

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::spread` - I think that is what you are trying to do in the first section

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  In your code, there is `funded`, but in the example, it is not showed

Comment: @akrun my mistake, `funded` corresponds to "Funding Received" in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what your final desired output looks like, but I think you can take advantage of the fact that logical values are coerced to integers and skip the creation of dummy columns.

```
library(dplyr)

byyear  <- original_data %>% 
   group_by(county, year) %>% 
   summarize(
       wasfunded = any(funded == "Yes", na.rm = T)
     , submittedapplication = any(submittedapp == "Yes", na.rm = T) # I'm assuming did/didn't submit is one of the other variables
   ) 

# if you don't need the byyear data for something else (I always seem to), 
# you can pipe that straight into this next line
yrs_funded_by_county  <- byyear %>% 
  summarize(
      n_yrs_funded = sum(wasfunded)
    , n_yrs_submitted = sum(submittedapplication)
    , pct_awarded = n_yrs_funded/n_yrs_submitted  # maybe you don't need a award rate, but I threw it it b/c it's the kind of stuff my grant person cares about
  )
```